# How does Rika still remain as a curse?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

There are some spoilers ahead as some parts of the following question involves parts from manga that aren't yet adapted to anime (Jujutsu Kaisen) yet.

> In Jujutsu Kaisen 0 movie, at the end of the movie Rika is released from her cursed form and hence takes her departure from Yuta. But in later parts of the manga, Rika is still present with Yuta in her cursed form and fights along with him. I don't get it - did she not get released or did she come back? What is happening exactly?

Comment: While this is perfectly on-topic here, maybe it would be easier to get an answer on https://anime.stackexchange.com (despite the url, it's about anime _and manga too_), where the [jujutsu-kaisen] tag is definitely more active.

Comment: @lfurini I had tried out that site initially with this question too, but it's not as active as this se. That's why I ask most manga & anime questions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far I found, in *Jujutsu Kaisen 0* Rika was released and she died. But what we see along with Yuta later on in the series is a result of his innate abilities. Yuta's ancestor was supposedly one of the three great apparitions of Japan and hence his abilities which allowed him to recreate Rika, which is however different from the first one; as now real Rika is dead, and this is the just curse which remains.